# Ways to improve macros execution time

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a macro, which runs fine but, for no reason I can explain, takes so long to finish. I have tried running the macro line to line and cannot figure out which part of the process takes so long. I can only imagine that it is the part where I delete rows based on backround color. I have built several macros with similar lines of code and the performance was way better.

```
Sub Pharma_Stock_Report()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim lastrow3 As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim DeleteRange As Range

spath1 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Pharma replenishment.xlsm"
spath2 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\NOT OK.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open spath1
Workbooks.Open spath2

Set ws1 = Workbooks("Pharma Stock Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Pharma Stock Report")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Pharma replenishment.xlsm").Worksheets("Replenishment")
Set ws3 = Workbooks("NOT OK.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws1.Cells.Clear

lastrow1 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws2.Range("A4:G" & lastrow1).Copy
With ws1.Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks("Pharma replenishment.xlsm").Close

lastrow2 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In ws1.Range("D2:D" & lastrow2)
    If Not cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Or cell.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
        If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteRange = cell
        Else
            Set DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
If Not DeleteRange Is Nothing Then DeleteRange.EntireRow.Delete

ws3.Range("H1:J1").Copy
With ws1.Range("H1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
End With

lastrow3 = ws1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range("H2:H" & lastrow3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:H,3,FALSE),"""")"
With Range("H2:H" & lastrow3)
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With

ws1.Range("I2:I" & lastrow3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE),"""")"
With Range("I2:I" & lastrow3)
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With

ws1.Range("J2:J" & lastrow3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:J,5,FALSE),"""")"
With Range("J2:J" & lastrow3)
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks("NOT OK.xlsx").Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Since this is working code, you'll get constructive help on coding style and ways to improve performance over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If your code works fine but needs tune-ups, put it up on [codereview.se] and **describe its purpose, what it does and how it does it and why it does it that way**, give it a title that summarizes the code's purpose, and folks on CR will be happy to help you improve your coding skills in every possible way, *including* performance.

Comment: Maybe throw in a few `Debug.Print Timer` in various places to see *where* the code is slow.

Comment: Also mention how many rows are involved in each sheet, and/or provide screenshots if possible.

Comment: I normally just click on a few places a debug point and click on play. That way you'll narrow down the troublesome area straight away - it's either the loop or the bit where you're pasting vlookup() down to last row - what is the last row?